# Content property not working in Firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, firefox

I want to display an image using content property in my project it is working fine on google chrome but not in Firefox or IE.
This is the HTML

```
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-1 col-sm-push-2">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/...">
                <div class="fb-logo"></div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

This is my CSS

```
.fb-logo{
  content: url(/assets/images/fb.png);
    width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 36px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fb-logo:after{
  content: url(/assets/images/fb.png);
    width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 36px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Please help me in finding a solution.

Comment: Since your logo is an image content so you are supposed to use <img> tag

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked your css and tested in chrome, firefox and IE, all worked as expected.

```css
.fb-logo::before{
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 36px;
  max-width: 36px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: green url("https://facebookbrand.com/wp-content/themes/fb-branding/prj-fb-branding/assets/images/fb-art.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.fb-logo-image {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 36px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-1 col-sm-push-2">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/...">
                <div class="fb-logo"></div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-1 col-sm-push-2">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/...">
                <img class="fb-logo-image" src="https://facebookbrand.com/wp-content/themes/fb-branding/prj-fb-branding/assets/images/fb-art.png" />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I've updated my answer so the icon has 36px of max-width. I've included another approach to use img tag and it's much better and semantically correct since your logo is a content.

Comment: which version of firefox and IE you are testing ?

Comment: I am currently with firefox and ie open. I can see facebook image here so it is working fine. Don't you see image in firefox or ie?

Comment: Works for me in all browsers

Comment: I believe max-width property is not working now in Firefox and IE iam on latest version of Firefox and IE

Comment: So what is actually your problem ? Is it content property not working or max-width not working ? If you see icon in all browsers then content property is working, if you want the icon to have 36px width then you need to be specific in your question that max-width is not working

Comment: I have updated my answer, click run code snippet to see how it works. Max-width actually works (add overflow: hidden to see) but it is overlaid by its big content (fb icon)